# Put Link in address bar without going to link

Tags: javascript

I am doing a lot of bookmarklet - ing and I am getting tired of typing `javascript:` every single time. I tried `javascript:window.location.replace('javascript:');` in a bookmarklet but that didn't work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What exactly are you tying to achieve ? could you give us an example of what you are trying to change. Like your workflow before and after adding this feature you are looking for

Comment: try `history.replaceState({}, '', '/your-path');` using [`history.replaceState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#The_replaceState()_method). it won't change your origin, just the path

Comment: I am looking for clicking a bookmark in a chrome new tab and javascript: appearing in the address bar

Answer (score 1):

You can use `window.history.replaceState({}, 'Page Name', URL);` to update the Address Bar without actually changing pages. Just be sure your app can handle that URL in case the page is refreshed or link is shared.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API